# Usage of 'one of the'

Tags: articles

Usually we prefer to use 'The' with single entity, but in case of 'one of the..', collection is used. E.g. On of the movies...
Can anyone explain is it correct usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We often use *the* with collections, groups, or plural nouns.

We do so when we expect our listener(s) or reader(s) to be familiar with that collection or group (to know which we are talking about):

> *All the Harry Potter movies.*
>
> *The people of France have elected a new president.*

We do not use *the* when we are talking about something in general (all of something):

> *Movies are expensive.*
>
> *People are all the same.*

If someone writes or says *One of the movies,* they believe that the listener or reader is familiar with the group of films of which one is of interest:

> *One of the movies nominated for best picture last year is an animated film.*

Answer (score 1):

In your case, 'the' does, in fact, still refer to a single thing:

> One of the movies

... refers to a single movie within a group. This usage is quite correct.